# Ajax Post not returning proper value

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

I am trying to verify if phone number exists in database when user fills in a number into the form field. I am using Ajax for post and return confirmation.

Everything seems fine except for an error when returning value from external file.

I am not able to pinpoint the exact error reason

The code is as follows

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {  

// check if input data is number

        $('#phone').keyup(function(){isNumber(this);});

 //Check the min chars for phone  
        var min_chars = 10;  
        //result texts  
        var characters_error = 'Has to be 10 digits only';  
        var checking_html = 'Checking...';  
        //when button is clicked  
        $('#phone').keyup(function(){  
            //run the character number check  
            if($('#phone').val().length != min_chars){  
                //if it's bellow the minimum show characters_error text '  
                $('#phone_availability_result').html(characters_error);  
            }else{  
                //else show the checking_text and run the function to check  
                $('#phone_availability_result').html(checking_html);  
                check_availabilityp();  
            }  
        });  
});      

//function to check phone availability  
function check_availabilityp(){  
        //get the phone  
        var phone = $('#phone').val();  
        //use ajax to run the check  
        $.post("check_phone.php", { phone: phone },  

            function(resultp){  
                //if the result is 1  
                if(resultp == 1){  
                    //show that the phone is available  
                    $('#phone_availability_result').html(phone + ' is Available');  
                }else if (resultp == 0){  
                    //show that the phone is NOT available  
                    $('#phone_availability_result').html(phone + ' is not Available');  
                }else{//show that the phone is NOT available  
                    $('#phone_availability_result').html('Something Wrong');}  
            });

        };  

//function to check whether input is number

 function isNumber(field) {
    var re = /^[0-9]*$/;
    if (!re.test(field.value)) {
        alert('Must be all numeric charcters. Non numerics will be removed   from field!');
        field.value = field.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g,"");
    }
}
</script>
```

HTML

```
<input type='text' id='phone' name="phone"  maxlength="10"> 
<div id='phone_availability_result'></div>
```

PHP Code 'check_phone.php'

```
<?php
include('connnew.php');
//$phone = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['phone']);  

$resultp = $usersdb->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE Phone = '$phone'") or   die($usersdb->error);  

//if number of rows fields is bigger them 0 that means it's NOT available '  
if($resultp->num_rows>0){  
//and we send 0 to the ajax request  
echo 1;  
}else{  
//and we send 1 to the ajax request  
echo 0;  
}  
?>
```

I am constantly getting the error "Something Wrong". Though when I independently run the check_phone.php file, it works fine. I guess it is in the return value function that there is some error.

Maybe somebody can help identify the bug.

Comment: try to add `resultp = resultp.trim()` because sometimes php return "[space]1" instead of "1".

Comment: And use console.log() in your script to check the value of `resultp`

Comment: On your page `check_phone.php` you commented the line `$phone = ...`, that mean `$phone` is not initialized and it should throw an error in your php side because you use it for your query.

Comment: @Rossi, yes that commented line was the issue. Though earlier it wasn't commented out and still gave the error, now it is working maybe the trim and / or the resultp='1'  as mentioned by Rijin all worked. Will check one by one to see which all were the issue. Though now it is working, thanks guys !

Comment: To update, it was the commented out line that was the issue. The script works with/without all the other additions.

Comment: use ajax in place of check_availabilityp() function in else condition. It will be better approach with few lines of codes.

Comment: I don't know how to move Rossi's comment to answer....

Comment: Ok Ravi, thanks for the suggestion. Will def work on that.

Comment: Please try exit at the end of php file it will give you correct result.

Comment: @user3526204 When your mouse is hover my comment, a left arrow append, click on it :D

Comment: @Rossi, no left arrow when I hover over your comment. Only the flag and vote icon on the left.  Nothing anywhere else on the comment.

Answer (score 1):

1. trim the response values before compare

   $.post("check_phone.php", { phone: phone },

   ```
       function(resultp){  
           //if the result is 1  
           if($.trim(resultp) == 1){  
               //show that the phone is available  
               $('#phone_availability_result').html(phone + ' is Available');  
           }else if ($.trim(resultp) == 0){  
               //show that the phone is NOT available  
               $('#phone_availability_result').html(phone + ' is not Available');  
           }else{//show that the phone is NOT available  
               $('#phone_availability_result').html('Something Wrong');}  
       });
   ```

---

2. $phone is commented in this code

   ```
       $resultp = $usersdb->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE Phone = '$phone'") or   die($usersdb->error);  


       if($resultp->num_rows>0){  

       echo 1;  
       }else{  

       echo 0;  
       }  

      ?>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

May be you are getting response as string, Try this :

```
if(resultp == '1' || resultp == 1) {  
    //show that the phone is available  
    $('#phone_availability_result').html(phone + ' is Available');  
}else if (resultp == '0' || resultp == 0){  
    //show that the phone is NOT available  
    $('#phone_availability_result').html(phone + ' is not Available');  
}else{//show that the phone is NOT available  
    $('#phone_availability_result').html('Something Wrong');
}
```

Comment: try to alert 'resultp', and see what you get

Comment: as I have commented above, now the script is working. I have included all the suggestions here. Will check one by one and update the implications here soon.